# How do you deal with situations where you can't use your preferred text editor?

Tags: editor, text-editor

I was originally going to frame this question around TextMate, which is by all accounts an amazing editor, but only available on OSX.  I was curious how those who have spent time learning to use TextMate efficiently deal with the situation where they have to edit on a non-OSX platform.  But it's really a more general question.  How do people deal with situations where you can't use your preferred text editor?

I use gvim and vim primarily, and I know that these editors have a rather esoteric set of keybindings, so when I'm editing in another editor I'll often mistakenly type things I didn't want to type while trying to navigate.  This can be very inefficient.

So how do people deal with these kinds of situations?  Just swallow the inefficiency?  Try to avoid the situation or go to great lengths to get the file that needs editing into your preferred editor?  Do you have one or two editors you're proficient with that you can switch between without problems?  Do you change the keybindings of other editors to more closely match your preferred editor?

Comment: This should be a community wiki. It's not programming related (although I agree it's "programmer" related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work as a support technician, which means I'm frequently working on customer systems remotely. The unfortunate side effect is that I rarely have any choice over what editor I get to use in those situations. Generally speaking there's not a whole lot you can do about it unless the situation is one where it's feasible for you to install a new editor or bring a USB thumb drive or something similar with your editor pre-installed on it. In such a situation, by all means, if you plan to be working for an extended time period, take advantage of the opportunity. You'll work faster and more efficiently and it will be less frustrating.

In an environment (e.g. webex/RDC) where you cannot install software or use temporary media, you have two choices: live with whatever editor they have, or copy files back and forth from your system. Typically if I'm doing very minor editing I just suck it up and use whatever editor is available. If I know I'm going to be doing an extensive amount of editing, I find a way to transfer the file I'm working on back and forth. This still stinks, forcing you to interrupt your editing flow with file transfers, but I find my sanity makes it worth not struggling with something like notepad to do real editing or programming.

Comment: The USB thumb drive is a great idea.  Unfortunately it wouldn't work so well for people whose favorite editor is only on one platform.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using either vim or emacs as an editor is precisely that it's available on virtually any decently configured Unix platform (and this includes more esoteric systems as well, e.g. Darwin/OS X). Combined with the fact that you can store your configuration online (e.g. [Dotfiles](http://www.dotfiles.com/)) this makes for a very strong argument, because the problem you described simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Since I work primarily in a windows environment, I keep [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) installed on a flash drive.  That way I can just pop the usb drive into a machine and have a quality editor, without having to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

On machines I'm using for longer periods, I use SciTE. I also use Dvorak keyboard. When guesting on machines, everything is different anyway as the keys are in illogical places. I just edit with what's there, or pass the file to source control and edit on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I resort to using notepad on win machines at client sites. Especially since I know that installing anything is not an option and I *know* that notepad will always be there.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only time this happens is when I'm using someone else's system since I typically install a text editor that I am reasonably familiar with on each system that I own/use regularly.  In that case, if I'm struggling too much, I move over and let the other person take the wheel (keyboard).  FWIW, I use TextMate (sometimes vim) on OSX, TextPad (sometimes Notepad or even Edit on servers not under my direct control) on Windows, and vim on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I got comfortable with a couple different editors - vi, eclipse, and PFE.  If I'm using some other editor short-term, I just deal with it.  If it's longer term, Google is my friend, and I go download one I like.

Answer (score 0):

On windows i convince everybody to install **notepad++**

On mac **TextMate** rules

On linux **vim**

Answer (score 0):

I use vi under linux and Ultraedit under Windows.
Vi is a must if you are doing some linux administration or if
you are working directly in a shell.

A mouse oriented editor is useful if you are working under a 
windowing system.

Anyway, I think you need to know the basics of both.

Answer (score 0):

I work regularly on Linux and Windows, and occasionally on OS X. Having to switch editors between them is a pain, so the obvious solution would be using some cross-platform editor. Right now I'm experimenting with Komodo Edit, which looks pretty promising.

If there's no decent editor in the machine, it doesn't take long to download and install one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming under windows you might want to take a look at [e text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) its basically TextMate for windows and supports the bundles and everything.